# array recognize same item name dont duplicate the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var idstore = new Array();

var item1 = ["display1, display2, display3, display4"];

var item2 = ["display1, display2, display3, display5"];

idstore.push(item1);
idstore.push(item2);

alert(idstore);
```

my intention is to make a array contain my name , and sometimes the name will be duplicate , how do i make the array check if the array had the same name ?. so mean if i have display1 on my idstore and i push item2 into it , it will recognize that idstore have display1 and dont duplicate same array name.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Tedeee/fyaekf7w/)

Comment: basically you have 2 arrays with one string in it.

Comment: @NinaScholz That must be a typo I believe.

Comment: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/t79r77nt/) Here is solution for you @darkness, i hope it will work you...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply with ES6,

```
var item1 = ["display1", "display2", "display3", "display4"];
var item2 = ["display1", "display2", "display3", "display5"];
var idstore = [...item1,...item2];
idstore = [...new Set(idstore)];
console.log(idstore); //["display1", "display2", "display3", "display4","display5"];
```

- Use [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for concatenating the array.
- Use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for creating a distinct set of elements.
- Again use spread operator to convert the set into an array.

Comment: `var res = [...new Set(item1.concat(item2))];`

Comment: @Tushar `var res = [...new Set([...item1,...item2])];` We can do it in a single line. For the sake of readability, I did like that in my answer,

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var idstore = new Array();
var item1 = ["display1, display2, display3, display4"];
var item2 = ["display1, display2, display3, display5"];
idstore.push(item1);
idstore.push(item2);
idstore = idstore.unique();
```